# camera not saving to specified file location android

Tags: android, camera

hi guys i'm using the camera application form my activity. using this line below i am trying to output the image to my specified location on sd card . it dosen't save the image to the location it gets from getImageUri() instead it  saves the file to camera gallery.any ideas what is going wrong.

```
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getImageUri());

//my getImageUri

private Uri getImageUri() {

    // Store image on sdcard

    String dir= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/my_app/Datapics";

    File dirs = new File(dir);
    if (!dirs.exists()) {
        dirs.mkdirs();
    }
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    CAPTURE_TITLE = extras.getString(some.NAME);
    //EDIT if i add this line here 
    CAPTURE_TITLE= "whatever.png";
    //it will save my picture to the folder i want it to save to but with name 
    //whatever.png i'm getting my name from my previous activity and want 
    //to assign it to capture title

    File file = new File(dir , CAPTURE_TITLE+".jpg");

    Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

    Log.e("get imageuri called: ",imgUri.toString());
//this is what I get from here
//04-28 19:42:33.835: E/get imageuri called:(2049):
 //file:///mnt/sdcard/my_app/Datapics/BlackbirdSat%20Apr%2028%2019%3A42.jpg


    Log.e("get imageuri called2: ",file.toString());
     //this is what i get here
//04-28 19:42:33.835: E/get imageuri called2:(2049)
//:/mnt/sdcard/my_app/Datapics/BlackbirdSat Apr 28 19:42.jpg
    return imgUri;

}
```

Comment: well i striped this activity out and created a separate app where i assigned the CAPTURE_TITLE as private static final and the app with one activity saved the file to the sdcard where i wanted it to. any ways around this.

Comment: oh just my imagination it works without final

Comment: for all the ppl i did not know of this. the names cannot contain : i was building the name using date and time which contained : so i used new Date().toString().replace(":"," "); and it saved my picture to my location.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some versions of Android and/or hardware not respect the `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` flag. I have this comment + solution in my code:

```
/*
 * HTC Eris and possibly other phones DONT respect the MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT flag and they only
 * return the image URI in the Data. In Android instances where the MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT *IS* respected
 * then Data is null. So use this fact retrieve the correct bitmap reference. When we have to return it from
 * Data then just copy it to the fileUri that we tried to store it in the first place via
 * MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT. 
*/


  private void gotoCamera() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    String mBoothFileName = "snap_" + (new Date()).getTime() + ".jpg";
    mStateHolder.mPictureFile = new File(((BatchApp) getApplication()).getStorageDirectory(), mBoothFileName);
    mStateHolder.mPictureUri = Uri.fromFile(mStateHolder.mPictureFile);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mStateHolder.mPictureUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
  }


/*
* When the post Camera activity returns
*/
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

  if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      /*
           * HTC Eris and possibly other phones DONT respect the MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT flag and they only
           * return the image URI in the Data. In Android instances where the MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT *IS* respected
           * then Data is null. So use this fact retrieve the correct bitmap reference. When we have to return it from
           * Data then just copy it to the fileUri that we tried to store it in the first place via
           * MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT. See how sneaky we are....
           */
      if (data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        try {
          InputStream input = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
          FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(mStateHolder.mPictureFile);
          /* 
          From Apache Commons IO: copy one stream to another:
          http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html
          */

          IOUtils.copy(input, output);
          mStateHolder.mPictureUri = Uri.fromFile(mStateHolder.mPictureFile);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          Toast.makeText(this, "Oops - couldn't capture your picture.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
      }
    }

    // you now have your image at "mStateHolder.mPictureUri"
    // do whatever you need to do ...

  }
}
```

Comment: i tryed this the if statment didn't get triggred so looked at whats in the data by data.tostring() and data.getData().tostring() in a try catch and i got the nullpointerexception.

Comment: IOUtils.copy(input,output).  It would be nice if you comment this line to explain what and there this line resolved to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly mention folder name where you want to put your camera image after getting the address of sd-card. Here I put "My Folder" where the image will be saved...

try this...

```
File defaultDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
// now specifing custom folder name in defaultDir
File myDir = new File(defaultDir, "My Folder");
// specify your picture name
String myPictureName = "Picture" + ".jpg";
// Making file name
String filename = myDir.getPath() + File.separator + myPictureName;
File pictureFile = new File(filename);
try {
    //Writing file to SD-Card
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
    fos.write(data);
    fos.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
// ---
}
```

hope this works...